# Como acessar uma tabela vinculada em access via C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-access

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazer uma consulta em um arquivo Access, porém não em uma tabela normal criada no Access e sim um arquivo vinculado(neste exemplo um txt).

O erro que deu quando fiz o select foi o seguinte:

```
O mecanismo de banco de dados do Microsoft Office Access não encontrou a tabela de entrada ou consulta 'Tabela'. Verifique se ela existe e se seu nome está digitado corretamente.
```

NOTA: Eu apenas quero consultar itens. Não desejo inserir nada.

- Edit - Código

  ```
  private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Triagem\TRIAGEM.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
      OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

      try
      {
          conn.Open();

          string SQL = "select endereco_cliente from TB_tempos_medios where ordem = '" + txtOrdem.Text + "'";
          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, conn);
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(dt);

          string enderecoCliente = null;

          if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
          {
              DataRow dtRow = dt.Rows[0];
              enderecoCliente = dtRow["endereco_cliente"].ToString();

              string SQL2 = "select ceco, ordem, endereco_cliente, municipio_cliente where endereco cliente like '{0}'";
              SQL2 = string.Format(SQL2, enderecoCliente);

              OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL2, conn);
              DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt2);

              gdvInfos.DataSource = dt2;
          }
          else
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Por favor, informa uma ordem válida.", "Ordem não encontrada", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw;
      }
      finally
      {
          conn.Close();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Coloque o código e dê mais informações para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Pronto. Adicionado

Comment: Veja isto: `string SQL2 = "select ceco, ordem, endereco_cliente, municipio_cliente where endereco cliente like '{0}'";` Onde está o `from`?

Comment: Eu errei ai mesmo, porém nem chega nesta parte do código. Quando ele chega no `da.Fill(dt);` ele já da erro.

Comment: Existe a tabela `TB_tempos_medios`? Nome ruim pra tabela. Este realmente é o código que está dando erro? Dê mais detalhes sobre o erro.

Comment: Existe a tabela sim. Isso ai é um arquivo de texto que está vinculado como Tabela no Access. Ele faz tudo até realmente buscar pela tabela. Acredito eu que ele não consegue achar a tabela vinculada, só tabelas realmente criadas pelo access, isso que eu quero saber.